# Pandas : Adding DateOffset vector to Date vector more efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas Index with Timestamps (*ind*) and a numpy array (*off*) with integers which represent the number of calendar days I want to add the *ind* Index.

For instance :

```py
    import pandas
    ind =  pd.date_range("2019-1-1T12:00", "2019-12-31T12:00", freq="D", tz="Europe/Paris")
    off = pd.np.ones(len(i))
```

I want to get the sum of the date (not datetime) of the first vector plus the number of days in the second vector.

Here is a code, which gives me what I want :

```py
    def f(ind, off):
        o = pd.Index( i.floor("D") + pd.DateOffset(days=o) for i,o in zip(ind, off) )
        return o

    o = f(ind, off)
```

But it is very slow (result of timeit for "o = f(ind, off)") :

```
126 ms ± 4.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

I guess it is because I use a python list comprehension instead of C functions from numpy or pandas.

With this in mind, here is an almost  working code which I wrote :

```py
    def g(ind, off):
        o = ind.floor("D") + pd.to_timedelta(off, unit="days")
        return o

    o = g(ind, off)
```

It is much faster :

```
1.28 ms ± 247 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

But it is also wrong, because it is adding 24H timedeltas instead of CalendarDays, which is not what I wanted since I am in the Europe/Paris timezone :

```py
    print( f(ind, off).hour.unique())
    print( g(ind, off).hour.unique())
```

Gives me :

```
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([0, 1, 23], dtype='int64')
```

I would like to have a solution as fast as my second one, but giving a correct answer like the first one. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the mad world of Daylight Saving Time. If you just do a quick compare between `f` and `g`, they match everyday, except the clock change days:

```
f = pd.Index([i.floor("D") + pd.DateOffset(days=o) for i,o in zip(ind, off)])
g1 = ind.floor('D') + pd.to_timedelta(off, unit="days")

# Show when f != g1
pd.DataFrame({'f': f, 'g1': g1}).query('f != g1')

                            f                        g1
89  2019-04-01 00:00:00+02:00 2019-04-01 01:00:00+02:00
299 2019-10-28 00:00:00+01:00 2019-10-27 23:00:00+01:00
```

So why is that? Mar 31 and Oct 27 are the two [clock change days in 2019](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/france/paris) for the EU. On Mar 31, the clock advances 1 hour ahead so a timedelta of 24 hours becomes 25. Conversely on Oct 27, the clock traces back 1 hour so 24 becomes 23. pandas was trying to accomodate the clock changes for you but it just happends that it's not what you want here.

There are a couple options I can think of...

One, convert all your dates to a single timezone (like Paris) then drop the timezone information with `tz_localize(None)`:

```
g2 = ind.tz_localize(None).floor('D') + pd.to_timedelta(off, unit='days')
pd.DataFrame({'f': f.tz_localize(None), 'g2': g2}).query('f != g2')         # empty frame
```

Two: do the `floor` operation after you have added the time delta:

```
g3 = (ind + pd.to_timedelta(off, unit='days')).floor('D')
pd.DataFrame({'f': f, 'g3': g3}).query('f != g3')       # empty again
```

Comment: Please be aware that the second options gives incorrect results on the clock change days if the time is not 12:00 as in the example but e.g. `2019-10-27 23:30:00` or `2019-10-27 00:30:00` (use `ind = pd.DatetimeIndex([pd.Timestamp('2019-10-27 23:30:00', tz='Europe/Paris'), pd.Timestamp('2019-10-27 00:30:00', tz='Europe/Paris')])` for the test)

Comment: So I guess the only valid option is `(ind.tz_localize(None).floor('D') + pd.to_timedelta(off, unit='days')).tz_localize('Europe/Paris')`.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I tried the tz_localize(None) and adapted it a bit, I dropped frop 129ms execution time to 1.28ms. Which uses this function a lot with more data dropped from 7s to 0.06s ! And the result is correct.

Comment: Thank you Stef, I had the same conclusion as you, my "adaptation" was exactly your proposition.